# git push to remote error: remote: warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files

Tags: git, git-flow

After I finish release on my machine... `git flow release finish 'X.X.XXX.X'` I then have to push the new release to origin. So I run these commands...

```
$ git push origin --tags (this works, results omitted)
$ git checkout develop (this works, results omitted)
$ git push (this works, results omitted)
$ git checkout master (this works, results omitted)
$ git push (this is what fails)
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
remote: warning: you may want to set your diff.renameLimit variable to at least 1804 and retry the command.
```

So, I have read a number of SO posts and the git-config documentation.  Based on what I read I set these values in my config...

```
$ git config merge.renameLimit 999999
$ git config diff.renameLimit 999999
$ git config diff.renames copies
```

Which results in this in the config file...

```
[merge]
    renameLimit = 999999
[diff]
    renameLimit = 999999
    renames = copies
```

But the same error happens.  I'm not sure what else to try.  Is `999999` too high of a value?  Is there a limit you can't exceed for it to work?  For `diff.renames` should it be `copies` or `"copies"` with double quotes?  I'll try all those options it just takes a long time to re-setup a test scenario.  [The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config) says `diff.renames` defaults to `true` but when I looked in my config it wasn't present that's why I added `copies`.

Here is my full config file in case it helps...

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.xxxxxx.com/gfrobenius/xxxxxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    bugfix = bugfix/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag = 
[gitflow "path"]
    hooks = C:/Users/gfrobenius/Sites/gfrobenius/xxxxxx/.git/hooks
[merge]
    renameLimit = 999999
[diff]
    renameLimit = 999999
    renames = copies
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> remote: warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
> ```

Any message that *you* see during a `git push`, that is prefixed with `remote:` like this, is coming not from *your* Git but from *their* Git.  No settings you make in your own repository will affect it.<sup>1</sup>

If they—whoever is the "they" that is receiving your `git push`—had a normal everyday repository, your `git push` from your `master` would send them your commits and ask them to set their `master` to identify the same commit as your `master`.  That either just succeeds right away (because the commit you've asked them to set is a descendant of the commit they already have as their `master`) or fails right away (because it's not).

We can therefore conclude that they, whoever they are, have fancied up their repository to run some special action when your `git push` asks their Git to update their `master`.  This special action of theirs is now running, and doing some sort of `git diff` command.  (The action is probably through a Git hook, such as a pre-receive or update hook.)

It's *their* Git that needs its rename-limit adjusted, to handle the difference between ... well, we don't *know* what they're `git diff`-ing!  We only know that they are running `git diff`!  So this is the point at which we have to *guess*.  There are a couple of reasonable things they could be doing, and many more unreasonable things.

They are almost definitely doing:

```
git diff <hash1> <hash2>
```

The *`hash1`* value *might* be the current value of their `master`.  If so, you can run `git fetch` (or even just `git ls-remote`) to see what hash ID *their* `master` represents.  The *`hash2`* value *might* be the hash ID of the commit in your repository that you call `master`, in which case you can just use your own name `master`.

If we get all of our guesses right, and also correctly guess at any settings *they* have set in *their* configuration, we might be able to reproduce whatever is going wrong in their pre-receive or update hook.

Of course, just being able to reproduce it doesn't enable us to fix it.  Only *they* can actually *fix* the problem.  At best, we could work around it, by pushing different commits.

The correct action at this point is to ask them what they are doing, why they are doing it, and whether you can improve that for them in some way.  If that fails, *then* go down this semi-blind alley of guessing what they're doing, and why, and whether and how you can work around their blunders.

---

<sup>1</sup>Modern Git actually has a way to send particular `variable = value` settings from one Git to another during a `git push`.  By default, these have *no effect at all* on the receiving Git, since otherwise you'd be able to trick existing, settings-naive Git receivers with these options.  But we know they have some sort of script they're using, from a Git hook; this script *might* actually look for such settings.

These settings are totally free-form, though.  Without some clue from them, there is no way for us to guess what settings might do something useful.  So once again, the correct action at this point is to talk to them.

Comment: I thought that might be it because the error came from “remote”. It’s our GitHub Enterprise server. I have control of it. But I couldn’t find where those limits could be configured on it. Sorry so short, stepped out of office.

Comment: Ah. Then you can make sure your hook(s) do the right thing. You would configure this in the actual repository on the server: log in, `cd` to the repository path, run `git config`. If there's some annoying web interface in the way, figure out how to work through it, or bypass it.

Comment: I do have a pre-receive hook that does a `git diff`.  I'm going to disable it and run this process again and see what happens.  If that is the culprit then I could disable the hook when doing a large release but I'd rather find out how to tweak those settings on the Enterprise server (if possible).

Comment: The error went away when the pre-receive hook was disabled.